# Common keyboard shortcuts for formatting

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I know that there are some almost universal formatting keyboard shortcuts like `Ctrl-b` for bold, `Ctrl-i` for italics, etc. What keyboard shortcuts would you recommend for preformatted text, (un)ordered lists, links and quotes for a generic WYSIWYG editor?

As the following list shows, there doesn't seem to be a universal agreement about the best option.

### Ordered lists

- LibreOffice: F12
- StackExchange: `Ctrl-O`
- Wordpress Editor:  `Alt + Shift + o`
- Gmail: `Ctrl + Shift + 8`

### Unordered lists

- Microsoft Word: -
- LibreOffice: `Shift - F12`
- StackExchange: `Ctrl - U`
- Wordpress Editor:  `Alt + Shift + u`

### Links

- CKEditor: `Ctrl - L`
- MediaWiki Editor: `Ctrl - K`
- Microsoft Word: `Ctrl - K`
- LibreOffice: `Ctrl - K`
- StackExchange:`Ctrl - L`
- Wordpress Editor:  `Alt + Shift + a`

### Headings

- LibreOffice: `Ctrl - (number)`
- Wordpress Editor: `Ctrl - (number)`

Maybe someone could make this into a community wiki to add more apps and formatting options?

Comment: While some actions, such as **I**talics and **B**old, suggest obvious keyboard shortcuts, others, such as in your list, will be primarily a matter of opinion.

Comment: Obvious? In most languages the word for bold does not start with a B, making it exactly very counter intuitive.

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: @BartGijssens Is this _What keyboard shortcuts would you recommend for preformatted text, (un)ordered lists, links and quotes for a generic WYSIWYG editor?_ I updated my question to be more specific.

Comment: @BartGijssens Some software like Microsoft Word have decided to use different keyboard shortcuts depending on language configuration. Although this might seem more intuitive, it breaks consistency in relation to the majority of software, which have English-based shortcuts.

Comment: While this list may be useful, it isn't really the sort of post that works on StackExchange sites. We're here to have a list of UX questions and their solutions. This is more of a blog article than a question. Community Wiki posts are not really used across the network anymore, save for on the Meta community sites because they don't adhere to the Q&A format the sites are based around.